# Railsでwebpackerを入れるとherokuへのデプロイでこける

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, webpack

## 環境

Rails 5.1.5
webpack 3.11.0

## エラーメッセージ

```
remote:        Webpacker is installed  
remote:        Using /tmp/build_a60546bb726d2fa7f4b8b4ac052f461e/config/webpacker.yml file for setting up webpack paths
remote:        Compiling…
remote:        Compilation failed:
remote:        bundler: failed to load command: webpack (/tmp/build_a60546bb726d2fa7f4b8b4ac052f461e/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/bin/webpack)
remote:        Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory - /tmp/build_a60546bb726d2fa7f4b8b4ac052f461e/node_modules/.bin/webpack
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 対策

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
heroku buildpacks:set heroku/nodejs
heroku buildpacks:add heroku/ruby
```

## 原因

heroku buildpacksのデフォルトのnode関連のエンジンのバージョンが古いためのようです。

## 参考

https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/739
https://github.com/rails/webpacker/issues/1282
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby/issues/712
https://qiita.com/tatsuyankmura/items/728e190b92e0370eefbb